# Prove by contraposition, if n is a positive integer such that n(mod3)=2 then n is not a perfect square

Tags: proof-writing

the question:

> Prove by contraposition, if $n$ is a positive integer such that $n(\mod 3)=2$ then $n$ is not a perfect square.

I've started by negating the statement, "Not q then not P":
Suppose if n is a perfect square, then n is not $2(mod3)$

Then:
if k(mod3) = 2, then k=3q, for some integer q. then $n=k^2, = 9k^2 = 3(3q^2)$ there $n(mod3) = 0$

Is what im doing correct? After this ill attempt $3n+1$ then $3n+2$

Comment: "if n is a positive integer such that n(mod3)=2 then n is a perfect square." is false. "Suppose if n is a negative integer such that n(mod3)=2 then n is not a perfect square." is true, but not the negation of the former

Comment: It should be: if $n=2 \mod 3$ then $n$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: $2$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: Yes, sorry that was a silly mistake haha

Answer (score 1):

$8\mod 3=2$ but $8$ is not a...

Answer (score 1):

The statement "if $n$ is $2$ modulo $3$, then $n$ is not a perfect square" has the contrapositive "if $n$ is a perfect square, then $n$ is not $2$ modulo $3$."  What you need to do is verify that this is true: for every perfect square...

I suggest looking at the squares of $3n$, $3n+1$, and $3n+2$, and verifying that they all satisfy this proposition (every number has one of these three forms).